# Connecting local php server with android devices

Tags: php, mysql

To connect local php website, i was able to connect from another pc in the same network by using ipaddress/foldername (eg. 192.168.1.1/test). I want to know that can i connect from android phone in the same wifi using the same method.

Comment: Ask this yourself, "Can I?" and then try to answer it by actually trying to access it from your android phone. I hope you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use ngrok for this:

[https://ngrok.com/](http://ngrok.com%20NGrok)

ngrok allows you to create a globally accessible domain name which directs to your local pc, especially useful for development.

Answer (score 0):

As your device in the same local network, it will connect to your local website on your way